# Maximum dev number in rfcomm bind

Tags: linux, bluetooth

`rfcomm bind` expects a `<dev>` argument to choose which `/dev/rfcomm<dev>` device name it should bind to.

What is the maximum number allowed as `<dev>`?

Let me rephrase: I can do `rfcomm bind 0 MAC`, `rfcomm bind 1 MAC`, etc... How far can I go with numbers?

Comment: Let me know what you determine since I totally don't understand what you're asking. You can run as many commands as you want and specify the one device per command. I'm not sure of any other limits and BlueTooth doesn't really have any rfc specs to get to the specific that I could find but I'm not really a linux guy nor a BlueTooth developer but I thought the man page for the command was clear for how to use the RFCOMM command but I'm missing something I don't understand so I've deleted it since it's not what you needed but I'm sure someone will help you out.

Comment: I'll try and find an answer. Thank you for all your time 